# How can I read an unreponsive text over a responsive design?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

Basically we have what is called a responsive design in HTML, but a part of real content served through our web page that comes from a very big database with product description was made with Dreamweaver.
Therefore its html is something like this:

```
<div style="width: 950px; float: left;">
<div style="width: 20px; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width: 910px; float: left; color: #37444D; padding-top: 20px; font-size: 18px;">...</div>
</div>
```

What can we do to avoid this unresponsive content to screw up the entire web page?

Comment: Stripping the presentation data out of the data in your database would seem like a good starting point.

Comment: @Quentin you mean stripping the html tags? (there are also images and lists...)

Comment: Just the tags and attributes that are presentational. Keep the ones for structure and semantics. (Add new structural/semantic elements when existing structure is only implied through presentation).

Comment: I'm afraid we can't do that as that would possibly mean to remove width and float on every element..
If we do that, that would break the graphics :s @Quentin

Comment: What graphics? You don't have to break anything. Move the inline CSS to an external stylesheet. Everything remains the same but now YOU have control of the styles and can change them for responsive views.

Comment: @Moob that's what a programmer would do (and that'd be GREAT), but ...well... that html coming from the database is like "marketing" stuff done by marketing people: it's been made by Dreamweaver, so every element has its own styling.

Comment: You can't put unresponsive elements into a responsive page and still expect it to work responsively.

Comment: LoL @Paulie_D I totally agree with you, try to explain this to my (complaining boss) ..but anyway: I was more looking for some workaround. I tried Overthrow... and I thought about using zoom in CSS, is it something feasible (to stretch that into specific widths

Comment: It wouldn't work anyway.You are injecting inline styles directly into the page...which would win any specificity war. You've got a massive problem that isn't going to be solved with a quick fix. The real resolution will require a complete addressing of your whole process...including the marketing people doing web design; something they are clearly not suited to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common real-world problem. In an ideal world the presentation and content would be separate, but here it sounds like there's too much legacy data to manually clean up.

In this case I'd recommend using Javascript to replace the inline styles with relevant class names.  The first thing this will do is remove all of your fixed widths, so you'll have something that fits with your responsive design.

However, many of those styles were actually doing *something* so you should then write some responsive CSS to target your new-found classes, which will all have sensible (if not semantic) names.

If your site runs jQuery the the code could be as simple as:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    $(this).addClass("width" + w);
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
});
```

Demo fiddle with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/5G374/1/